# undefined reference to ffmpeg functions in native code using Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, cmake, java-native-interface

I have a problem with using ffmpeg in Android Studio 2.2 using NDK 13 and new Cmake building system. FFmpeg version is 3.1.4.
The system I'm working on is Linux Mint 18 64-bit.
At the build time I'm getting undefined reference error each time I use ffpeg functions.

My MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Example of a call to a native method
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
    tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    public native String stringFromJNI();

    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }
}
```

My native class (undefined reference is pointing to av_init_packet(&avPacket)):

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>


extern "C"
jstring
Java_com_example_tito_jnitest_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {

    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNItest", "Hello from JNI!");

    AVPacket avPacket;
    av_init_packet(&avPacket);

    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

build.gradle script

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tito.jnitest"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                // Passes optional arguments to CMake.
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
                abiFilters 'armeabi'
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['/home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/src/main/jniLibs']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

include_directories(/home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/ffmpeg-3.1.4/android/${ANDROID_ABI}/include)

#set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

add_library( avutil
             SHARED
             IMPORTED )

set_target_properties(
                avutil
                PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                /home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libavutil-55.so )

add_library( swscale
             SHARED
             IMPORTED )

set_target_properties(
                swscale
                PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                /home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libswscale-4.so )

add_library( swresample
             SHARED
             IMPORTED )

set_target_properties(
                swresample
                PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                /home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libswresample-2.so )

add_library( avcodec
             SHARED
             IMPORTED )

set_target_properties(
                avcodec
                PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                /home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libavcodec-57.so )

add_library( avfilter
             SHARED
             IMPORTED )

set_target_properties(
                avfilter
                PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                /home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libavfilter-6.so )

add_library( avformat
             SHARED
             IMPORTED )

set_target_properties(
                avformat
                PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                /home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libavformat-57.so )

add_library( avdevice
             SHARED
             IMPORTED )

set_target_properties(
                avdevice
                PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                /home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libavdevice-57.so )

add_library( native-lib
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

find_library( log-lib
              log )

target_link_libraries(native-lib ${log-lib} avutil swscale swresample avcodec avfilter avformat avdevice)
```

Build process of ffmpeg seemed to be successful. Here's my build script:

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
function build_one
{
./configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--disable-static \
--enable-shared \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-doc \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=arm \
--enable-cross-compile \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic -marm" \
--extra-ldflags="-marm" \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=armeabi
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
build_one
```

One thing I noticed that could indicate that something is wrong with ffmpeg build is warning `WARNING: /home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config not found, library detection may fail.` during building. I'm not sure if this may be cause of problems.

I was trying to build for all of the ABIs, but for now I decided to focus on making just armeabi working. I'm having exact same failure after using e.g. arm64-v8a.

Finally, here is the gradle console's content with error:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateJsonModelDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:externalNativeBuildDebug
  building /home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi/libnative-lib.so
:app:externalNativeBuildDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing '/home/tito/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake' with arguments {--build /home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi --target native-lib}
  [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
  [2/2] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi/libnative-lib.so
  FAILED: : && /home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  -target armv5te-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain /home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -fPIC -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -frtti -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi/libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o  /home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/liblog.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libavutil-55.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libswscale-4.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libswresample-2.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libavcodec-57.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libavfilter-6.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libavformat-57.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libavdevice-57.so -lm "/home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a" "-latomic" && :
  /home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:18: error: undefined reference to 'av_init_packet(AVPacket*)'
  clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: Build command failed.
Error while executing '/home/tito/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake' with arguments {--build /home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi --target native-lib}
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi/libnative-lib.so
FAILED: : && /home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  -target armv5te-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain /home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -fPIC -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -frtti -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi/libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o  /home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/liblog.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libavutil-55.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libswscale-4.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libswresample-2.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libavcodec-57.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libavfilter-6.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libavformat-57.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libavdevice-57.so -lm "/home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a" "-latomic" && :
/home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:18: error: undefined reference to 'av_init_packet(AVPacket*)'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:228)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:621)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:604)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: Build command failed.
Error while executing '/home/tito/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake' with arguments {--build /home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi --target native-lib}
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi/libnative-lib.so
FAILED: : && /home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  -target armv5te-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain /home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -fPIC -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -frtti -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi/libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o  /home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/liblog.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libavutil-55.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libswscale-4.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libswresample-2.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libavcodec-57.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libavfilter-6.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libavformat-57.so ../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libavdevice-57.so -lm "/home/tito/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a" "-latomic" && :
/home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:18: error: undefined reference to 'av_init_packet(AVPacket*)'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeBuildTaskUtils.executeBuildProcessAndLogError(ExternalNativeBuildTaskUtils.java:233)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeBuildTask.executeProcessBatch(ExternalNativeBuildTask.java:231)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeBuildTask.build(ExternalNativeBuildTask.java:163)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    ... 77 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.723 secs
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: you have all of the imported libs copied into your configured folder, /home/tito/AndroidStudioProjects/JNItest/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/, before starting to build in android studio? for this case, ${ANDROID_ABI} is armeabi. Your cmakelists.txt will not build them here.

Comment: @Gerry Yes, I have them copied there. CMake logs implicit message if they are not in there while building.

Comment: your code downloadable somewhere? those libs are build with ndk-build or some sort tools for android, I assume.

Comment: @Gerry No, it's not downloadable. I've tried to post all of the important code in question, and the whole project is based on https://github.com/sengsational/HelloCv. FFmpeg builds are build with  standard Android NDK toolchains.

Comment: thanks!  Let me download and try it ( just carious ), and let you know.  from the scripts you post, I did not see anything incorrect.

Comment: wired, I have to re-type in the lib name, maybe that one was using strange editor :
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
include_directories(../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include)
add_library(native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )
add_library(lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_opencv
                      PROPERTIES
                      IMPORTED_LOCATION
                      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)

target_link_libraries( native-lib android log lib_opencv)

Comment: in that build.gradle file, your jniLibs is at the default, you do not need to set it there. If you set, use gradle syntax ( forward slash, not windows syntax ), otherwise, the proj could not build on linux /mac.  I will find time to create a pull request for that repo

Comment: add a PR to github.com/sengsational/HelloCv, feel free to comment on it. Built on Mac/Windows, runs on Nexus 9